# Keep hyperlinks intact while converting to pdf in Microsoft Word 2011

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word

I have a table of contents with both hyperlinks and URL hyperlinks that aren't acknowledged when I convert a Word document to a pdf file. I was surprised not seeing this question already on stackoverflow. Any tips?

Comment: Is this Word on Windows or OSX? If it's OSX, this might provide some insight:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1323421

Comment: It is OSX, and opening in Open Office to convert from there works! I can't believe there's not an easier way, though!

Comment: I'd be happy to give you the answer points if nobody comes up with anything better!

Comment: I think you're a bit better qualified to explain in detail what worked for you (i.e. answer your own question). But thanks for the offer!